# how to properly import java jar modules using sublime text 2 and opensuse 13.1 (package does not exist error) without IDE?

Tags: java, import, jar

I use InteliJ IDE, but now I need to compile the code on the server without the IDE. How would I specify the path to the .jar files, and import classes from them to compile the code?

```java
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestMessageReceiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String region = "eu-west-1";
    // TODO: specify correct queue name

    String queueName = "ajax-<name>-events-demo.fifo";
    // Creating credentials from accessKey/secretKey pair
    // Use accessKey/secretKey values provided by Ajax
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "accessKey",
            "secretKey"
    );
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new
            AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
    AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(region).build();
        
    // Getting queueUrl to connect
    String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl(queueName).getQueueUrl();
    
    while (true) {
        ReceiveMessageRequest receiveRequest = new
                ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl)
                .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10).withWaitTimeSeconds(20);
        List<Message> messages = 
        sqs.receiveMessage(receiveRequest).getMessages();
        if (messages.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Received messages: " + messages);
        // Deleting received and processed messages from the queue
        List<DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry> deleteEntries = 
        messages.stream().map(message -> new                    
        DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry(message.getMessageId(),
            message.getReceiptHandle())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        DeleteMessageBatchRequest deleteRequest = new
            DeleteMessageBatchRequest(queueUrl)
            .withEntries(deleteEntries);
        List<BatchResultErrorEntry> failed = 
        sqs.deleteMessageBatch(deleteRequest).getFailed();
            
        // Checking if there is any issue with deleting messages 2.
        if (!failed.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Failed to delete next messages: " + 
            failed);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Successfully deleted all the messages.");
        }

    }
}
```

I have error package com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model does not exist.
This is Opensuse 13.1

Comment: How do you compile it? What is your classpath? Is the aws library in your (compile) classpath? You can specify the classpath with `-cp`.

Comment: I compile it in the console. My command:  javac TestMessageReceiver.java -cp home/usr/share/java/aws-java-sdk-1.12.10.jar, aws library I put in home/usr/shere/java dir.

Comment: I used the path /usr/share/java/aws-java-sdk-1.12.10.jar, and instead of 50 errors, I have 3, now I don't know how to add the path to additional libraries